# To find the last updated record of each month for each policy(another field)

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, teradata

I have a table named `a`, and other fields as `eff_date,policy no`.

Now for each policy, consider all the records, and take out the last updated one (`eff_date`) from each month.

So I need the last updated record for each month for each policy. How would I write a query for this?

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: For which RDBMS is this? It is important to extract the months and group by a combination of month and policy_no.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100 percent on Teradata syntax, but I believe you're after this:

```
SELECT policy_no,eff_date
FROM (SELECT policy_no,eff_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY policy no, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eff_date),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM eff_date) ORDER BY eff_date DESC) as RowRank
      FROM a) as sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

I'm assuming when you say by month you also want to differentiate by year, but if not, just remove the EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eff_date) from the PARTITION BY section.

Edit: Update for Teradata syntax.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not very familiar with Teradata, can you run the inside query without issue?

Comment: SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY policy_no, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eff_dt),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM eff_dt) 
ORDER BY eff_dt DESC) 
      FROM a

Comment: What if you list out the fields instead of using *?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() is a function that adds a number, like ranking to each result row.

Comment: This is retrieving all the dates of a month. I am not getting only the last updated date record of a month. And also policy no is displayed as 1,2,3 etc.. not the original policy nos

Comment: Yes, the inside query adds a row number to every date, the outside query then limits based on the rowrank, which is limited to the last update for the month, review updated answer.

Comment: Hope its working fine. but the policy nos are displayed as 1,2 etc..i need the real policy nos to be displayed

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from a 
qualify ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY policy no, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eff_date),
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM eff_date) ORDER BY eff_date DESC) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difficulty, is that the `group by` needs to be made both the conbination of policy_no, but also the month (extracted from the date).  For example:

**In Mysql**

```
    SELECT policy_no,
       month(eff_date),
       year(eff_date),
       max(eff_date)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY policy_no,
         month(eff_date),
         year(eff_date);
```

### Update

I saw derived tables are allowed in teradata. Using a join to a derived table, here is how to access the full rows:

```
select * from a,
(SELECT policy_no,
       month(eff_date),
       year(eff_date),
       max(eff_date) as MaxMonthDate
FROM a
GROUP BY policy_no,
         month(eff_date),
         year(eff_date)
 ) as b
where a.policy_no = b.policy_no and
a.eff_date = b.MaxMonthDate;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f728/5

### Update (Using Extract)

```
select * from a,
    (SELECT a2.policy_no,
           EXTRACT(MONTH FROM a2.eff_date),
           EXTRACT(YEAR FROM  a2.eff_date),
           max(a2.eff_date) as MaxMonthDate
    FROM a as a2
    GROUP BY a2.policy_no,
             EXTRACT(MONTH FROM a2.eff_date),
             EXTRACT(YEAR FROM  a2.eff_date)
     ) as b
    where a.policy_no = b.policy_no and
    a.eff_date = b.MaxMonthDate;
```

Comment: From the question I think that op wants the last updated row (as in, every column) per month per policy. Not just the max date.

Comment: Thanks, that has been remedied.

Comment: not really. You are still just taking the max value for `eff_date`, when I believe that he want the **whole** row for that max `eff_date`. This is accomplished on Goat_CO's answer

Comment: @user2497982, I have updated my query to provide all info using  a join to a derived table.

Comment: Throwing an error "All expressions in a derived table must have an explicit name"

Comment: I suspect instead of `month()` and `year()` functions, teradata may use `Extract(MONTH FROM field)` or `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM field)` . Also, the problem may be you need to add `b.` prefix to `MaxMonthDate` so: `b.MaxMonthDate` in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest looking into Windows Aggregate functions and the QUALIFY statement. I believe the following SQL will work.

```
SELECT Policy_No
     , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Eff_Date) AS Eff_Month_
     , Eff_Date
  FROM TableA
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Policy_No, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Eff_Date) 
                           ORDER BY Eff_Date DESC) = 1;
```